# Delphi JSONValue get value

Tags: delphi

I have arrived up to here with my code:

```
JSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Text) as TJSONArray;

for var JSONValue in JSONArray do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(JSONValue.Value);
  end;
```

Please note that `Text := '[{"jahre":2},{"jahre":4},{"jahre":15}]'` which is a valid JSON format. How can I get 2019 and 2018 items in the list?

With the above code I get white items in the list box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each `JSONValue` is a "piece" of your array and each piece is an object. You have to convert the type to `TJSONObject` and the you can get the value.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add((JSONValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('jahre').ToString);
```

More info can be found [in the doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/JSON) (if you're using 10.3 the JSON library has been improved)